# App build.gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio

This is happening after I launched AVD for app test, and it was starting android OS. few seconds later, my computer( using Mac) was restarted by causing error Android Studio. After the happening, my Android Studio is strange.

- It was working well, but it suddenly happened.
- Android Studio does not still work after I used a Clean Project ,and it can't recognize things such as `R.` , all those methods.

Thank you :)

I attached the screenshot for your understanding.

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the app's build.gradle, the Manifest, and the styles.xml

Comment: Thanks to all. it is now working well. Just check dependency in build.grade(Module:app). and paste this, compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `styles.xml` is error. So you have to fix it and clean your project. 
I think you are trying to add `AppCompat` to your project. Did you add the following line in your dependencies?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Hi Pham, yeah there it is. it was fine but after android studio crashes, it is still showing. and I just tried to use the menu Invalidate and Restart, it still now working :(

Comment: So just put your own answer and mark it as solved or closed thread :)

Comment: @SengJoonHyun That is likely not necessary

Comment: I commented worng place:( Did you use: Menu tab - > Build - > Rebuild Project

Comment: @NgocThangPham yes , I did

Comment: @NgocThangPham it is working well on another PC.. I think like what cricket_007 said that Gradle problem error.

Comment: You just need create new project in the same PC. Don't need to use another PC. Sometimes I get this error. And It's the final solution for me.

Comment: @NgocThangPham Thanks. it is now working well. As you said, when it, android studio crashed, it might lose build.gradle(Module : app)'s settings. Just create a new project and open its build.gradle, then copy it to the previous project which is having errors. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the same compile SDK version and the app compat version. Check your gradle file.

For example, if you are compiling with SDK 23

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

You must use the same app compat version 23.x.x

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
```

Comment: Hi José Carlos, Thank you, and now it is working well :). Good Day !